# Getting Default Rules in Drools rule engine from excel

Tags: templates, jboss, drools, kie

Below is the image for excel rule sheet (basic syntax).
[image]

Now in 4th rule where my store number is * now I am trying to add a rule such that if any rule is not executed from row 1 to 3 then only my 4th rule should execute irrespective of any store.

Now I tried with adding **agenda-group so that priority is given to row 1 to 3**. But how to check if none(1 to 3 rows) is executed then my 4th rule should run.

But in drools irrespective of executing 1 to 3 rows that fact is trying to check 4th rule.

**How to make sure to run 4th only when other rows not executed.**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a control fact, rules #1 to #3 will insert an object inside the working memory inside the consequence and the rule #4 will check that object is not present.

It's a common pattern in Drools and I think it might be better suited in your case instead of using ruleflow-groups.

I've talked about control facts in [this video](https://youtu.be/IdS7dgSj3ds?t=2751) and there's also an example in Drools' [codebase](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/36eccb8a33550eb2049255f058fe016c6a1fa2f7/drools-examples/src/main/resources/org/drools/examples/fire/simple/Fire.drl#L44-L50)

Comment: Is "control facts" the official name for these things? I've always heard them referred to as "flags" (or similar names).

Comment: TBH I don't think there's an official name, I think that if you use  "control facts" you can be easily understood in the community. "flag" sounds more like a boolean (which BTW can totally be also a control flag) while "fact" reminds of an actual object

Answer (score 1):

While the flag / control fact flow is one possibility (as described by Luca in the other answer), the other is to have your "default" rule go first, and then subsequent rules overwrite the results.

So if your rules are setting a 'valid' indicator to true, then your default rule setting it to false should go first, and then the other rules can override it as needed.

Functionally the workflow would be equivalent to this Java code:

```java
boolean valid = false; // "default" rule sets this in all cases
if ( condition1 ) { // "rule 1" sets to true
  valid = true;
}
if ( condition2 ) { // "rule 2" sets to true
  valid = true;
}
// etc.
// if no "rules" hit, default value from "default rule" remains
```

The "control fact" flow is equivalent to this code:

```java
boolean valid;

boolean hasRuleHit = false;
if (condition1) {
  valid = true;
  hasRuleHit = true;
}
if (condition2) {
  valid = true;
  hasRuleHit = true;
}
// etc

if (!hasRuleHit) {
  // "default" rule only triggers if the "flag" doesn't indicate that any other rule has hit
  valid = false;
}
```

Structurally the difference between the two is that the the "default first" workflow requires that you enforce order in your rules either by salience or by intentionally never using salience and listing that default rule first; and the "control fact" flow will increase your memory footprint because you are inserting data into working memory.